# Origin not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin with TYPO3 FE-Login

Tags: .htaccess, cross-domain, typo3

I've been looking at plenty solutions for the "Origin http://example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" but I couldn't fix mine.

There is an admin area where you need to log in to view the page. When you hit the submit button, nothing happens. Looking into the console, it throws following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.example.com/index.php?eID=FrontendLoginRsaPublicKey. Origin
>   http://example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I've literally added an Access-Control-Allow-Origin wildcard in every .htaccess I could find, but without effect. Does anyone has a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. The wrong XMLHttpRequest was related to the config.baseURL which pointed to https://www.domain.ltd.

When you open the page with http://www.domain.ltd/loginpage.html the login process will not work, because the asynchron request is send to the https version of this page. I set the login page to https (settings > behaviour > protocol), so typo3 will do a 301-forward if the user hits the non https version.

Now the login is working without any errors.

Also make sure that you access the page with the domain registered in baseURL. If you access http://domain.ltd/loginpage.html and http://www.domain.ltd/ is set in baseURL the error occurs too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the new **jsonp** ?? into your ajax request.

```
dataType: "jsonp",
jsonpCallback: "localJsonpCallback"
```

Here is an example: https://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/